# No slime spawning in slime chunk 2018 1.12.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found a slime chunk right inside my straight mine so I dug out a 16x16x3 chunk at level 19 and coordinates 71 19 -120. I have lit up the room light levels are above 10 everywhere and there are no other mobs spawning inside.

I have been waiting for about an hour afk with the game active at around 32 blocks away (coordinates are 90 11 -125) in order to get some slimes to spawn but still not even one.

- Confirmed slime chunk with - http://chunkbase.com/apps/slime-finder#-1729309068124591226
- The height level is below 40
- Several nights have passed
- Player position is around 32 blocks away from the center of the slime chunk (coordinates of center 7 19 7)
- Playing on 1.12.1 without any mods
- There isn't a huge stack of monsters around the slime chunk (there is a ravine right above it but its lit up)
- I searched for questions like this but they were mostly either related to a different problem that I have already solved or from 2+ years ago.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: What do you mean with "7 19 7"? If it's coordinates, it's far away. If it's chunk section numbers, you're above maximum build height.

Comment: I don't know if 3 blocks height is enough for slimes. Have you confirmed that that works somewhere else?

Comment: What's the current moon phase? Slime spawning rates depend on that.

Comment: The moon phase has cycled a few times from full to new. 7 19 7 is the chunk coordinates this means the center of the chunk. They are only provided to show what i mean by center of chunk. The coordinates provided above are the global coordinates at which I stay to see if slimes will spawn. How can I check if 3 blocks high is enough for slimes ?

Comment: A 3 block gap is tall enough for slimes to spawn.  My slime farms always have a 3 block gap between platforms.  Can you upload the map so we can look at specifics?  I am currently recreating your world to try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "chunk coordinates". Chunks have numbers that are a 16th of the lowest coordinate of that chunk, not the center, if you mean that. In any way, I don't know where you get the 19 from when talking about chunk numbers.

Comment: You can check if 3 blocks is high enough by trying the same thing in a creative world, then try it with 4, then 5 etc.

Comment: [Big slimes need 3×2½×3 area to spawn.](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Slime#Spawning)  I see what you mean.  I recreated the world with the world seed with cheats.  I built the same room and lit all the caverns.  Nothing spawned a slime.  I used the fill command to build a full spawn room with multiple platforms.  I checked the seed with a few different slime chunk tools.  They all say it's a slime chunk but I have no slime spawns.

Comment: So is the seed clunky and not giving correct info about the slime chunks?

Comment: It is a slime chunk.  I have now had 2 slimes spawn in that chunk.  The spawn rate is terrible.  If that chunk is dark, the monster spawns in that chunk are low as well.  I lit a lot of the caves in the area as there are a lot.  During the day I used `testfor @e` to see what mobs exist and don't suspect I have reached the hostile cap.  Even when I use `kill @e[type=!player]`, I don't generally see spawns.

Comment: Soo.. there is a spawn rate for every chunk ? or is it just bad luck?

Comment: There is not a spawn rate per chunk.  There is a [mob cap](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn#Mob_cap) which is based on available chunks.  If you are in single player, the hostile mob cap is 70.  If there are 70 other hostile mobs already in your world, no more will spawn and that includes slime.  The less monsters in the world, the more slimes will spawn.  This is why you have to light up caves and the surface.  I can't tell if that is the problem with this seed/chunk or not.  I assume I missed some caves.  I've built several slime farms and never had this much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates you give are only about 21 blocks apart. Assuming that you have given the center of your farm (71,19,-120) and the location you are standing (90,11,-1225) you may not be far enough away.